# Get a file from external link and store into local server

Tags: php

I need to get an image file from external link and store into my local folder.

I have used following:

```
 $value1 = "https://images.airlist.com/0008459/Listing/129128/3350520160227084506.JPG%3Fv=1?v=1";

 $img_file = file_get_contents(str_replace("?v=1","",$value1));
 $file_handler = fopen($file_loc,'w');
 if(fwrite($file_handler,$img_file)== false)
    {
            echo 'error';
    }
    fclose($file_handler);
   }
```

Image is stored in a format like:

> 3308420160227084509.JPG%3Fv=1-50x50.jpg%3fv=1

Comment: use `file_put_contents(DESTINATION, file_get_contents(URL))`

Comment: Is it your actual code? You should put some quote around the URL...

Comment: Here image stored like (2997720160227084507.JPG%3Fv=1); unsupported format. can't open the file .

Comment: yes. This is my actual code.

Comment: Let me get this straight, your question is how to turn `https://images.airlist.com/0008459/Listing/129128/3350520160227084506.JPG%3Fv=1?v=1` into `3350520160227084506.JPG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would do something like:

```
$url = "https://images.airlist.com/0008459/Listing/129128/3350520160227084506.JPG%3Fv=1?v=1";
$file = explode('?', $url)[0]; // get everything on the left site from the ?
$file = explode('%', $file)[0]; // get everything on the left site from %
$filename = basename($file); // get only the filename
$fileContent = file_get_contents($url); // get image content
file_put_contents($filename, $fileContent); // write image content to filename
```

Comment: If suppose I remove the %3Fv=1 . No image return from the link .

Comment: when I remove the %3fv=1 . I Got The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:71bb7efd-0001-001b-140c-7656a5000000 Time:2016-03-04T11:56:19.2772739Z.

Comment: Thanking ,Its Working Now .

Answer (score 0):

You didn't answer my comment an hour ago, but I'll go by the assumption that you want to *download* `https://images.airlist.com/0008459/Listing/129128/3350520160227084506.JPG%3Fv=1‌​?v=1` and *save* it as `3350520160227084506.JPG`.

```
<?php

$value1 = "https://images.airlist.com/0008459/Listing/129128/3350520160227084506.JPG%3Fv=1?v=1";

// Take the basename (3350520160227084506.JPG%3Fv=1?v=1)
// And remove anything starting from either a percent sign (%) or a question mark (?)
$fileName = preg_replace('~[%?].*$~', '', basename($value1));

// $fileName = string(23) "3350520160227084506.JPG"

file_put_contents($fileName, file_get_contents($value1));
```